# Why is the sequence important for matrix transitions like rotate and translate transform at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, matrix, internet-explorer-10

I want to animate a matrix3d with rotation and translation at the same time. The strange thing is i get completely different results putting the rotation first or the translation first.
i have two fiddles to show the difference. i dont understand that.

http://jsfiddle.net/wetlip/2nuQu/   rotate before translation

http://jsfiddle.net/wetlip/Z3MTX/   translation before rotate

```
var el = document.getElementById("aa2");
 var matrix = new MSCSSMatrix(el.style.transform);

    matrix = matrix.rotateAxisAngle(0, 1, 0, 85);
 matrix = matrix.translate(300, 0, 0);

 el.style.transform = matrix;
```

gives a quite different result as

```
var el = document.getElementById("aa2");
 var matrix = new MSCSSMatrix(el.style.transform);


 matrix = matrix.translate(300, 0, 0);
matrix = matrix.rotateAxisAngle(0, 1, 0, 85);


 el.style.transform = matrix;
```

Answer (score 1):

These operations are applied via matrix multiplication which isn't commutative.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Rotation occurs about the origin.

If you want to rotate an object that is not at the origin you have to first translate it to the origin, rotate it, and then translate it back.

If you rotate an object that is not at the origin you effectively move and rotate it in an unexpected way.

Comment: okay , clear but i cant find any matrix mathematics which includes the origin concerning css